# How to make text-overflow with ellipsis work with long strings that have no breaks

Tags: html, css

I set up a webpage like the one detailed here: http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail
(An example can be found here: http://alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_4.html)

My problem (which may sound contrived and if that bothers you, let's take this as a fun exercise in CSS) is that if you take out all the spaces and any other characters that allow a string to break, the text will overflow or get hidden behind the right column:

[image]

The ideal solution is to put an ellipsis whenever that happens so that the user knows that there's text being hidden. (Note that I don't want to force breaking between letters because the rest of the paragraph has normal-sized strings that should break on spaces or punctuation.)

I can't seem to get `text-overflow` to work anywhere. The best I can do, it seems, is to just apply `overflow: hidden` but that's a severely less-than-ideal solution.

Can anyone show me (using CSS only, hopefully. I'm not interested in doing text calculations in JavaScript) how I might be able to add an ellipsis for this particular problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this css

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: white-space:nowrap; would result in all other text not wrapping and according to that picture it seems he wants to wrap whitespace as usual only eclipse too long string